# How to make a bot join a channel and respond in chat discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I just started learning to code very recently in order to make a discord bot in python. I have used both pieces of code separately and they have worked, but when trying to use them together only the messages work, and the bot will not join the voice channel.

No errors come up when I type the join command.

However, I can't seem to find the error. If someone could look over my code and find where I'm going wrong, it would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
@client.command
async def join(ctx):
  if (ctx.author.voice):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
  else:
    await ctx.send("I am terribly sorry, but I cannot join you as you are not in a voice channel.")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  msg = message.content
  
  if any(word in msg for word in stimulus_words):
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(stimulus))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your code looks pretty good for someone new to Discord.py

The problem comes from the fact that your `async def join(ctx):` is not *registered* as a command by discord. This can be done by adding `@client.command()` on top of your function. This way it will be recognized and called with the context when someone uses $join  ($ = a prefix that you chose for your bot). You can find more information [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)

Also, I would recommend looking into [Cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html) that are a good way to organise your code

PRE-EDIT : I see you edited your code to add the decorator on top of your function, however you are missing the `( )` so this is why it is not working in my opinion

Comment: Thank you for responding so fast! I tried adding the `( )` but that did not change anything. Do you see anything else that I could have done wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the bot can see the channel then? Are you sure the command is not called ? What happens if the first line of your join command prints something, does it show ?

Comment: After testing without the code `@client.event` and everything after, the bot is able to join. When I tried to print something with all the code, nothing is printed

Comment: It's also not working because he didn't process commands with `client.process_commands`

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Thank you for pointing that out! Now with that implemented, the code is working. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you make a command in discord.py, you have to type `@client.command()` (so call the function), unlike `@client.event`.

This is what your function should be:

```
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
  if (ctx.author.voice):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
  else:
    await ctx.send("I am terribly sorry, but I cannot join you as you are not in a voice channel.")
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but when I first posted I accidentally did not copy that part of my code, but it was in there. Do you have any other ideas as to why this would not be working?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to have the bot respond to certains prompts try the following:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
     if message.author == client.user:
         return

     if '#your prompt here' in message.content:
              await message.channel.send('#your response here')
```

Or if you want the bot to only look at the beginning of the message try:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
     if message.author == client.user:
         return


     if  message.content.startswith('your prompt here'):
              await message.channel.send('#your response here')
```

I can also give you samples of how to get the random choice stuff to work if you are having trouble with that.  I am also fairly new to coding & just created my bot a few weeks back.  Been having a lot of fun putting it all together.